# Tkinter frame freezes when destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program which has a main menu and when buttons are pressed other menus pop up destroying the previous. Destroying the main menu works perfectly as intended. However it's when I try and destroy one of the submenus is when things get ugly.

The menu just freezes and my computer is stuck loading when I hover over it with my mouse. The only way to close it is by killing it by closing the shell which is what I have been doing. My friend reckons it's because I use a Mac and it's just a bug and I shouldn't worry about it but I thought I might as well try and see if anyone here knows how to fix the issue. Here is some example code for the main menu:

```
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = '#8BDFF4')
frame.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.5)


button1 = tk.Button(frame, text = "view table", bg = '#8BF4AB', fg = 'black', activebackground='#62AF7A', command = view)
button1.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 0.25,relheight = 0.25)
root.mainloop()
```

When the 'view table' button is pressed the main menu is destroyed and the new menu under the view command is now active. This works fine. here is the code for the view menu:

```
def view():
    frame.destroy()
    HEIGHT = 700
    WIDTH = 800

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width = WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()
    #Renamed the second frame
    framee = tk.Frame(root, bg = '#8BDFF4')
    framee.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.5)

    button1 = tk.Button(framee, text = "inflows", bg = '#8BF4AB', fg = 'black', activebackground='#62AF7A', command = viewin)
    button1.place(relx = 0, rely = 0.35, relwidth = 0.25,relheight = 0.25)
```

Now I renamed it to `framee` to keep it separate from the main menu. The issue comes when I press the button and the `viewin` command runs this is when the freezing occurs. Here is the code I use for `viewin` to close `framee` down:

```
def viewin():
    framee.destroy()
```

Like I said this freezes the window up completely and im not really sure what to do about it this is kind of my last resort. sorry the post is kind of long just wanted as much detail as possible so the issue could be fixed.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. It's hard to know how to stitch this code together to make it work.

Comment: `framee` is a *local variable* within `view()`.  `viewin()` cannot access it, unless that function was actually indented to be inside of `view()` (and would also have to be before the point where you do `command=viewin`).

Comment: no this is not the case the program  wants to destroy framee as it freezes and I do not get any errors saying framee is not defined also have made framee global and there is no change